# how to simply style in scss so that multiple elements will use same style

Tags: sass

I am new to sass.

Here is my code in scss. Just wondering if this can be simplified further i.e i dont want to repeat the style color, text-decoration and transition.

```
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

div.menu-item-click {
    &:hover, &:focus {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.3s;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, so you may check some more uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note exactly that use case is covvered better by [ReSedano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852979/how-to-simply-style-in-scss-so-that-multiple-elements-will-use-same-style/52853038#52853430).

You cand do it using mixins:

```
@mixin mixinName {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

a {
    @include mixinName;
}

div.menu-item-click {
    &:hover, &:focus {
        @include mixinName; 
    }
}
```

Also here is example with variables:

```
@mixin icon($width) {
    width: $width;
    stroke: currentColor;
}

.icon {
    @include icon(25px);
}
```

And here is example with body

```
@mixin desktop ($xl: null) { // look here is default Value!
    @media (min-width: if($xl, $xl, $screen-desktop)) { 
       @content; // here is true magic
    }
}

.page {
    @include desktop { // you may ignore variable because we have default
        padding: 30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll add some more intresting examples later on

Answer (score 1):

For this, maybe it is better using a placeholder with `@extend` directive (the output is less verbose than using a mixin):

```
%my-class {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

a {
    @extend %my-class;
}

div.menu-item-click {
    &:hover, &:focus {
        @extend %my-class;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
a, div.menu-item-click:hover, div.menu-item-click:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```